# How to detect if the Kotlin Multiplatform app for iOS is running on a simulator?

Tags: swift, kotlin, macros, kotlin-multiplatform

In Swift we have:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
foo
#else
bar
#endif
```

How to achieve the same in KMM for iOS? There are no macros in Kotlin.

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/Platform.kt - not 100% but you could try to check `OsFamily` and `CpuArchitecture`

Comment: I have tried OsFamily and CpuArchitecture. When I run on a simulator on my M1 pro MBP, I get IOS and ARM64. The same on my iphone.